# How to retrieve multiple values from JavaScript variable and pass it to Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Script**

This my Javascript script at the bottom within the HTML file:

```
var savedValues = []
var currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value

function handleChange() {
// The new values for the fridge with id currentId:
var temp = document.getElementById("temperature").value
var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value

// Save these values for the previous id
// - First, check to see if we already have a record we can update
var save = savedValues.find(save => {
  return save.id === currentId
})
// - If we do, update it, otherwise create a new record
if (save) {
  save.temp = temp
  save.comments = comments
} else {
  savedValues.push({
    id: currentId,
    temp: temp,
    comments: comments,
  })
}

// Update the current id to the newly selected option
currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value
```

**This is the output on console in Google Chrome**

```
{…}]
0: {id: "Fridge 1", temp: "", comments: ""}
1: {id: "Fridge 2", temp: "3", comments: "a"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Node JS**

**I have a controller**

```
exports.getData = async function(req, res) {
  var {savedValues} = req.body;
  console.log(savedValues);
}
```

**Details**

This currently doesn't do anything.

**Question**

How can I get any variable from JavaScript script and use it in Node JS?

**Goal:**

I am aiming to get values from JavaScript script to use in Node JS to insert into MySQL database.

**Full HTML Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav>
      <h4>Technical</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          {{#if user}}
          <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>


        {{else}}
          <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
        {{/if}}
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container mt-4">
      <h1 class="text-left" style="margin-bottom: 50px">Daily Fridge & Freezer Monitoring Record</h1>
        <form action="/auth/21-TEMP-01b" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Fridge Or Freezer</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="fridgeFreezer" name="fridge">
              <option value="Fridge 1">Fridge 1</option>
              <option value="Fridge 2">Fridge 2</option>
              <option value="Fridge 3">Fridge 3</option>
              <option value="Fridge 4">Fridge 4</option>
              <option value="Fridge 5">Fridge 5</option>
              <option value="Fridge 6">Fridge 6</option>
              <option value="Fridge 7">Fridge 7</option>
              <option value="Fridge 8">Fridge 8</option>
              <option value="Fridge 9">Fridge 9</option>
              <option value="Fridge 10">Fridge 10</option>
              <option value="Freezer 1">Freezer 1</option>
              <option value="Freezer 2">Freezer 2</option>
              <option value="Freezer 3">Freezer 3</option>
              <option value="Freezer 4">Freezer 4</option>
              <option value="Freezer 5">Freezer 5</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Temperature °C</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="temperature" name="temperature">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

var savedValues = []
var currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value

function handleChange() {
// The new values for the fridge with id currentId:
var temp = document.getElementById("temperature").value
var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value

// Save these values for the previous id
// - First, check to see if we already have a record we can update
var save = savedValues.find(save => {
  return save.id === currentId
})
// - If we do, update it, otherwise create a new record
if (save) {
  save.temp = temp
  save.comments = comments
} else {
  savedValues.push({
    id: currentId,
    temp: temp,
    comments: comments,
  })
}

// Update the current id to the newly selected option
currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value

// Load any previously saved data for this new id
save = savedValues.find(save => {
  return save.id === currentId
})
// If we find a previous value, load it, otherwise empty the inputs
if (save) {
  document.getElementById("temperature").value = save.temp
  document.getElementById("comments").value = save.comments
} else {
  document.getElementById("temperature").value = ''
  document.getElementById("comments").value = ''
}

console.log(savedValues);

}

// Attach the event listener to the document
document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);


  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What ajax methods or libraries are you using?

Comment: If your elements are inside a form then you can use req.body using express

Comment: @Rod911 I am using express, handlebars as my view engine.

Comment: if you are intend to submit the form as form data, how about set a hidden value in your form, and `el.value = JSON.stringify(savedValues);` when form.onSubmit ?
Another way is to add <input name="savedValues.0.comments" /> (0 is the index of the array). Or if you would like to submit it via js, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest/send , or using jQuery is kind of easy way to do AJAX call. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @AllenWong If I hide it - the values are there to be edited within the console.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Just set the value in `<input type="hidden" />` right before form submit should be okay, you can keep the old code for editing the values after submission if you want.

Comment: @AllenWong Let's say I inspect element and find that `hidden input` I can manually edit the `JSON` values within the console

Comment: you mean you dont want ppl to manually edit the JSON object via console? so instead of keep generate savedValues and set it in `<input type="hidden" />`, you should do `$('form').on('submit', function() { // set hidden value;  return true; // continue to submit form });` to set that value right before form submission. Thats only one of the solutions, you can submit the object as jsonData via javascript using ajax too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js/4296402#4296402

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make a route in your `node.js` and then when you submit the form you make a post call to the route from your javascript

```js
const form = document.getElementById('user-form') //give your form an id
form.addEventListener('submit', submitform, false) //add event listener 
var submitform = function sbmform(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // prevent submission
  submitvalues() // exec function 
}
var savedValues = []

function submitvalues() {
  var currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value
  // The new values for the fridge with id currentId:
  var temp = document.getElementById("temperature").value
  var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value

  // Save these values for the previous id
  // - First, check to see if we already have a record we can update
  var save = savedValues.find(save => {
    return save.id === currentId
  })
  // - If we do, update it, otherwise create a new record
  if (save) {
    save.temp = temp
    save.comments = comments
  } else {
    savedValues.push({
      id: currentId,
      temp: temp,
      comments: comments,
    })
  }

  // Update the current id to the newly selected option
  currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value

  data = {
    data: savedValues
  }
  // make an call to submit the values 
  fetchobj = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
  url = "your route url"
  fetch(url, fetchobj)
  form.removeEventListener('submit', submitform, false);
  form.submit()

}
```

Comment: in your javascript in your html page

Comment: Below my current javascript script? p.s thanks for quick response

Comment: and what would i do in node js to receive it?

Comment: in the `submitform(){}` function in the answer  add your code inside (the code that gets the values ....)and  an api call to the a route in your node js

Comment: you could use the same route as the one in the form to receive the values or make one if you use `express` in your node just do somthing like `app.post('\name-your-route',(req,res)=>{})`

Comment: let me know if you need more help

Comment: Have you got a youtube video or something I can learn in depth?

Comment: nothing comes to mind at the moment but I am pretty sure there are plenty of good tutorials there

Comment: do you know how to use node.js and make a route?

Comment: Just at the basics - just trying to learn by creating something. I understand the `get` `post` methods and how to interact the form with node js

Comment: from your javascript code I think you want to mimic updating values in the database, if that's what you want, then you should move your javascript code from front end (html) to backend node.js and handle the new values there

Comment: I think I need a re-think to my structure. In terms of Front-End maybe instead of storing all data to 1 variable which at the moment it is:`savedValues`, I maybe should have multiple forms. This will make it easier for me to create functions such as `This form is not filled out - please fill all data`.

Comment: I suggest you get this example working first and learn from it and then change it after this way you will learn about 2 different approaches and which one works better for you

Comment: Very good point - I will see where I get to with this :D

Comment: Saving the values in your front end is definitely not a good idea because you will be exposing your data and anyone can change it

Comment: the code I added above will allow you to make your code work buy sending the values

Comment: I have updated the code and added your js code in it and a fetch to your node route check it out

Comment: problem with that code is - I cannot save values for each fridge from the dropdown